# AngularJS ui-bootstrap: Datepicker not working in month mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am unable to use AngularJS' **ui-bootstrap's datepicker** in the month mode.

Here's a [plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/2yhm7phjlj1zwbWWC6Cu?p=preview)

Here's my **template**:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">

      {{dt}}
      <datepicker ng-model="dt.from" datepicker-mode="mode" min-mode="mode"></datepicker>
      <datepicker ng-model="dt.to" datepicker-mode="mode" min-mode="mode"></datepicker>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my **JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.dt = {to: '', from: ''};
  $scope.mode = 'month';

})
```

Whenever I click on a month, it changes to the **'day'** mode. This is working fine in the day mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as-is with the latest version of Bootstrap UI (also requires a later version of Angular).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kg2OEYvP8MF4nUxfjB4a)

If upgrading is not an option then hard-coding min-mode to month also works.

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt.from" datepicker-mode="mode" min-mode="month"></datepicker>
<datepicker ng-model="dt.to" datepicker-mode="mode" min-mode="month"></datepicker>
```