# Angular ui-bootstrap: dropdown not working with version 0.13.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was successfully using ui-bootstrap's dropdown menu with version **0.11.0** as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Hi {{"{{user.fName}}"}} !<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="settings">My Account</a></li>
                              <!--   <li class="divider"></li> -->
                                <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onclick="LogOut()">Log Out</button></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

But, I needed to use **datepicker's month mode** which required me to upgrade to **0.13.3**. Here's my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334710/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-not-working-in-month-mode) explaining that.
Here's a common [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2yhm7phjlj1zwbWWC6Cu?p=preview).

But, now my dropdown menu has stopped working. On clicking it, no dropdown shows but also there is no error. Any idea how I should tackle this?

Comment: Hi Pierre, I have added a plunker in the question. Can you please help there?

Comment: Well, your plunker is working fine.

Comment: check now I was trying from the docs. Now you'll see the datepickers working properly, but the dropdown isn't. However, if you change the version to 0.11.0, the dropdown will start working but the datepicker would stop working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, you have to use the directive dropdown, not only the class.

```
 <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
             <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Hi !
             <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="settings">My Account</a></li>
          <!--   <li class="divider"></li> -->
          <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onclick="LogOut()">Log Out</button></li>
       </ul>
 </li>
```

Simply add `dropdown` and `dropdown-toggle` on your HTML tag will do the trick.

[**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JCULTtJBU0OANwiVMHXC?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, it seems 0.11.0 supports not adding a directive and works with just a class.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the fact that it was even possible to use only the class.

Comment: yes, its funny but it was working with just a class in the 0.11.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Pierre, I had to add **attributes 'dropdown' and 'dropdown-toggle'** rather than classes in version 0.13.3 as compared to 0.11.0. Changing the markup from:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Hi  !<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="settings">My Account</a></li>
                              <!--   <li class="divider"></li> -->
                                <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onclick="LogOut()">Log Out</button></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

to

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                          <li dropdown>
                            <a href='#' dropdown-toggle><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Hi {{"{{user.fName}}"}} !<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="settings">My Account</a></li>
                              <!--   <li class="divider"></li> -->
                                <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onclick="LogOut()">Log Out</button></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

did the trick.